# How to add dates to remote sensing data?

Tags: r, datetime, matrix, time-series, r-raster

I am working with remote sensing data to create time series of NDVI and Cloud cover. The data consists of 30 rows (latitude) and 40 columns (Longitude) and 212 matrix slices which are the months from 2000-03 until 2017-10. How ever R sees the data as an array and there is no date visible in the data. Except that I know that the 212 matrix are the months. How can I add a date to the matrix slices but still have the latitude and longitude to work with?

When I use:

```
NDVI_timeserie <- ts(name.ts.ndvi, frequency=12, start=c(2000,3))
```

This gives the correct time to the data but then it is not saved as date. So when I want to select only the rain season, I can't because I can't select the months and years.

I am open to suggestions and advice of creating a time series.

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about your data and what your goal is? Maybe you can share `str(name.ts.ndvi)`